# LINQ to SQL sum of decimal values

Tags: linq-to-sql, decimal, sum

I can't figure out how to do a simple sum of decimal values.

```
Table<StaffTime> times = ctx.GetTable<StaffTime>();

var query = from t in times
            select new 
            {
               t.Hours.Sum()
            }
```

Isn't Sum an extension method? What am I missing?

Bob

Comment: As a tip, for code fragments, use the 101010 button to format them (otherwise you lose line breaks, generic parameters, etc.).

Comment: Hi bobuva - it looks like you've asked a number of questions on SO but haven't marked any answers as "accepted".  If any answers to your questions solved your problems, you should go back through them and mark an accepted answer using the checkmark icons in the posts.

Answer (score 6):

Sum is an extension method over `IEnumerable<decimal>` (or int or whatever).  t.Hours is a *single* decimal value (I assume), so can't be summed.

If you want the sum of hours, write `times.Sum(t => t.Hours)`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var sum = (from t in times select t.Hours).Sum();
```

This is of course assuming that `t.Hours` is one of these types:

> `Decimal`
>   `Double`
>   `Int32`
>   `Int64`
>   `Nullable<Decimal>`
>   `Nullable<Double>`
>   `Nullable<Int32>`
>   `Nullable<Int64>`
>   `Nullable<Single>`

Comment: Andrew,

I'm creating an anonymous type using select new, as below:
var query = from t in times            
select new             
{               
   t.Hours.Sum(),
   t.StaffID,
   ...
};

I'm not sure I can use the Sum extension method in this case.

Comment: You are correct - the `Sum` method wouldn't work for your case then.